Movie about a serial killer 'in-training'
I'm looking for this horror movie I watched quite a while ago, not exactly sure when, maybe ~2006? Might be later too, really don't remember.
It's about this guy who wants to become a serial killer just like in the movies, complete with all the tropes, like walking slowly when they're looking at you and then sprinting when they're not to keep up to scare the victims and athletic training to appear in unlikely spots to cause panic.
He's followed by a film team through all this (but the movie isn't shown from their perspective, like REC or Blair Witch Project are), who he "betrays" in the "final exam" and hunts instead.
Anybody know what I'm talking about? Some of the information might be wrong, but this is how I remember it.

Sounds like Behind the Mask: The Rise of Leslie Vernon from 2006. 

The next great psycho horror slasher has given a documentary crew exclusive access to his life as he plans his reign of terror over the sleepy town of Glen Echo, all the while deconstructing the conventions and archetypes of the horror genre for them. 

Here's the trailer:




Yup that's it, thanks! Surprised at 2006 actually being accurate.
